# RAM for vCPUs on gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How do I know the exact RAM of the CPU instance that I have created on gcloud? I have created an instance with n1-standard-8 (8-vCPUs, 30GB memory). Is this RAM? When I am trying to run a model it gives me out of memory error saying I tried to allocate 12GB.

Hence, I want to know what is the RAM for my instance , and how can I increase it to run my model?

Answer (score 1):

This [guide](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types) describes the available different machine types. According to the document your mentioned machine type explain here:

```
n1-standard-8: Your machine type

8-vCPUs: For the n1 series of machine types, a vCPU is implemented as a single hardware hyper-thread on a 2.6 GHz Intel Xeon E5 (Sandy Bridge), 2.5 GHz Intel Xeon E5 v2 (Ivy Bridge), 2.3 GHz Intel Xeon E5 v3 (Haswell), 2.2 GHz Intel Xeon E5 v4 (Broadwell), or 2.0 GHz Intel Skylake (Skylake).

30GB: Your system memory(RAM)
```

Also, you can run this following [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/describe) in your [Cloud Shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/) to displays all data associated with a Google Compute Engine virtual machine instance:

```
gcloud compute instances describe INSTANCE_NAME [--zone=ZONE]
```

In the meantime, you can run `free -m` command in your machine to see the total and free memory of your instance if you are using a Linux machine.

The instance must be shutdown in order to edit it and increase the RAM or/and CPU. You can find More information in this [article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/changing-machine-type-of-stopped-instance).

Comment: Thanks for your answer and all the links. But if the RAM is 30GB then why is it running out of memory for allocation of 12GB? I also tried the free -m command. It seems like the data on instance is also occupying some of this 30 GB which is counterintuitive to me since I thought that RAM is for processing only. But it makes sense if that is the only memory available to the instance.

Comment: You can run `vmstat -s` or `top` command to see if any other application is using a lot of memory in your VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be the system RAM you can adjust while creating an instance or template. To check the available RAM on the instance (and assuming you are using Linux), connect to it using the Google SSH shell and type `top` command. It should display the memory available and in use, as well as the current processes.